# What types of wood (other than plywood) can a staple gun penetrate?

Tags: wood

I am going to build a shelf for my cat by wrapping a layer of faux fur fabric around a plank of wood. I have a mechanical staple gun and the fabric, now I just need to buy the wood.

Other than plywood, what types of wood would be appropriate for this project given the following considerations:

- Lightweight, since it will be mounted on a wall
- Able to be easily penetrated with a mechanical (non-electric) staple gun
- Does not use chemicals in its manufacture (like glue is used to make plywood)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pine comes to mind immediately. Most big box home centers will carry a selection of 1"x pine- that is perfect for shelving.

Another option would be poplar, though it's a bit more expensive (generally).

Any softwood would do, but those two are the most common.

Comment: Poplar is a "hardwood", although it's not as hard as some others like oak and maple.

Comment: After some research, it looks like pine boards will be the best option. Thanks!